# Error parsing XML mismatched tag

Tags: android, xml, parsing, tags, mismatch

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="About the course"
                    android:textColor="#0000ff"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="This course equips you the skills to handle and manage the technology that is so vital in the field of media and communication, namely digital communication, wireless devices, broadband, media design and other emerging media and telecommunication technologies."
                    android:textColor="#0000ff"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="214dp"
                    android:layout_height="171dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/cinema4d"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#0000ff"
                    android:text="What you learn:"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#0000ff"
                    android:textSize="14dp" 
                    android:text="Enrol in subjects on the fundamentals of media and communication technology and refine your specialisation by choosing elective subjects in areas such as multimedia networking and applications, wireless and mobile communications, and digital broadcasting with emphasis on a 'hands-on. minds-on' approach."/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="214dp"
                    android:layout_height="171dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/fdmp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />                
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

my code was fine and i tested out a few times and it work until the error parsing xml mismatched appear and i can't seem to find the error.
After i add the imageview the following error appears when i try to build :
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
    - The element type "LinearLayout" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
Does someone know whats wrong with my code?
thanks

Answer (score 9):

The error message is quite accurate:

> Multiple annotations found at this line: - error: Error parsing XML:
>   mismatched tag - **The element type "LinearLayout" must be terminated
>   by the matching end-tag**

Your xml opens up two `<LinearLayout>` tags (one on the first line, one as the first element of the `<ScrollView>`) but it only closes one.

Adding a `</LinearLayout>` before `</ScrollView>` should resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `</LinearLayout>` tag before your `</ScrollView>`