# Resource compilation failed error: mismatched tag

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\TTP\AndroidStudioProjects\TicCrossGame\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:94: error: mismatched tag.

i check tags closing but unable to understand erorr because i check all closing tags but still erorr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="395dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="126dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="126dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cross" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Remove duplicate closing tag </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error parsing XML mismatched tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043170/error-parsing-xml-mismatched-tag)

Comment: The problem is that you close two times the GridLayout tag, anyway, can you describe how you want your layout to look like? Probably there's a better way instead of using GridLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two closing GridLyout tags. Remove one of these at the bottom of your XML file:

```
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two closing tags for the `GridLayout` just remove one of them and your code should work fine. Like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="395dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="126dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="126dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cross" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```